# Stripping white spaces in dictionary with recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to strip the white spaces in keys and values of a dictionary:

**The dictionary**:

```py
a = { "a ": { " b ": { "c ": " d " }}}
```

and I want the output as :

```py
a = { "a": { "b": { "c": "d" }}} #white spaces removed from keys and values
```

The code I tried:

```py
def rspace(d):
  for k, v in d.items():
    if type(v) != dict:
      d[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    else:
      rspace(d[k])

rspace(s)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in rspace
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in rspace
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in rspace
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

```py
def rspace(d1,d2):
  for k, v in d2.items():
    if type(v) != dict:
      d[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    else:
      rspace(d1[k],v)

d1 = {}
rspace(d1,a)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in rspace
KeyError: 'a '
``
```

Comment: Build a new dictionary instead of modifying the existing one in-place - even if it worked, this would still have the old keys in too.

Comment: ok i will do that @JohnColeman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
def stripspace(dictionary):
    result = {}
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result[k.strip()] = stripspace(v)
        else:
            result[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    return result
```

Calling the function:

```
print(stripspace(a)) # a = { "a ": { " b ": { "c ": " d " }}}
```

This prints:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}
```